# iOS/PhoneGap App Orientation Changed After Using Camera

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, camera, orientation

I am having a problem with the iOS/PhoneGap app that I am working on. The app is setup to be oriented in landscape only. The app works great until after I use the camera to take a photo. After taking ,saving, and displaying the photo in the app, the orientation is changed to portrait, even though the iPad is still in landscape position. The app is not sideways or anything, I just have a large black space on the right side of the screen as if a portrait app was being displayed on a landscape screen. Has anyone else had this problem? Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: you can do this our server side image rotate function. I have done this using php service side imagerotate function.